# Script in HP-UX can't create or overwrite files

Tags: shell, unix, hp-ux

I'm trying to build libxml2-2.7.8 on HP-UX 11ia32 and the configure script is stuck at

```
echo "$ac_script" 2>/dev/null | sed 99q >conftest.sed
```

And I believe its due to the script not being able to create files. I'm assuming this because it is unable to overwrite the config.log file when rerunning the script. I've triple checked permissions, and I've chmod the entire folder with 777.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like `noclobber`.  The [manual](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/hp-ux/man1/sh-posix.1.html) lists two ways to modify that setting:

```
  % set [{-|+}abCefhkmnopstuvx] [{-|+}o option]...
       [{-|+}A name] [arg]...

       Set (-) or clear (+) execution options or perform array
       assignments (-A, +A).  All options except -A and +A can be
       supplied in a shell invocation (see the SYNOPSIS section and the
       Shell Invocation subsection).

       Using + instead of - before an option causes the option to be
       turned off.  These options can also be used when invoking the
       shell.  The current list of set single-letter options is
       contained in the shell variable -.  It can be examined with the
       command echo $-.

       The - and + options can be intermixed in the same command, except
       that there can be only one -A or +A option.

       Unless -A or +A is specified, the remaining arg arguments are
       assigned consecutively to the positional parameters 1, 2, ....

       The set command with neither arguments nor options displays the
       names and values of all shell parameters on standard output.  See
       also env(1).
...
       -C   Prevent redirection > from truncating existing files.
            Requires >| to truncate a file when turned on.
...
       -o   Set an option argument from the following list.  Repeat the
            -o option to specify additional option arguments.
...
           noclobber      Same as -C.
```

That is,

```
set +C
set +o noclobber
```